# Getting url auto redirect issue at debug point

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, debugging

I am using testng, maven framework for my selenium automation using Java on eclipse. I had once manually changed browser url on reaching debug point in eclipse, and now every time where ever i put debug point, browser url gets automatically redirected to that url

Comment: Try providing a more detailed explanation of your problem. A question with too little detail is unlikely to get good responses. See this link for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask